# Do Arabic characters have different Unicode code points based on position in string?

Tags: unicode, arabic

Do Arabic characters have different Unicode code points based on position in string, or is it a visual solution?

This is the same word, 3 times, with white spaces and without
seems like it's the same Unicode value.

عربى‎
عرب ى‎
ع ربى‎

What I need to do, is to scan a list of Arabic strings, and get their values.  Using those values, I will choose the icon of the specific letter to display. 
However, if it's the same code point, the meaning is that I need to create a logic of my own in the code, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Please read the Wikipedia entry on Arabic in Unicode. The answer is: possibly. Isolated shapes may get rendered differently by text rendering engines and/or by OpenType instructions in the font file itself.

Comment: The answer is “yes”. In Arabic script the letters change shape depending on the surrounding letters. And the different shapes of a letter are represented by the same code point.

Comment: @roeland: Except it's not that simple, because Unicode also provides code points for initil, middle and final forms of letters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Different shapes have different unicode, for example the letter ت `\u062A` has all those codes for different shapes: `\uFE95` ﺕ , `\uFE97` ﺗ, `\uFE98` ﺘ , `\uFE96` ﺖ.

Though, mostly, Arabic texts are kept with the main unshaped unicode. shaped forms are used only in rendering. so if you check your text through a program, you will find it mostly unshaped.

If you want all letters shaped, you may use a reshaper library like: [Python Arabic Reshaper](http://mpcabd.xyz/python-arabic-text-reshaper/):

```
   import arabic_reshaper
   reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(u'اللغة العربية رائعة')
```

If you want all letters unshaped, use the shaping map down to convert letters to their main shape.

Here is a shaping map:

```
SHAPING = {
 u'\u0621' : ( u'\uFE80' ) ,
 u'\u0622' : ( u'\uFE81', u'\uFE82' ) ,
 u'\u0623' : ( u'\uFE83', u'\uFE84' ) ,
 u'\u0624' : ( u'\uFE85' , u'\uFE86' ) ,
 u'\u0625' : ( u'\uFE87' , u'\uFE88' ) ,
 u'\u0626' : ( u'\uFE89' , u'\uFE8B' , u'\uFE8C' , u'\uFE8A' ) ,
 u'\u0627' : ( u'\uFE8D' , u'\uFE8E' ) ,
 u'\u0628' : ( u'\uFE8F' , u'\uFE91' , u'\uFE92' , u'\uFE90' ) ,
 u'\u0629' : ( u'\uFE93' , u'\uFE94' ) ,
 u'\u062A' : ( u'\uFE95' , u'\uFE97' , u'\uFE98' , u'\uFE96' ) ,
 u'\u062B' : ( u'\uFE99' , u'\uFE9B' , u'\uFE9C' , u'\uFE9A' ) ,
 u'\u062C' : ( u'\uFE9D' , u'\uFE9F' , u'\uFEA0', u'\uFE9E' ) ,
 u'\u062D' : ( u'\uFEA1' , u'\uFEA3' , u'\uFEA4' , u'\uFEA2' ) ,
 u'\u062E' : ( u'\uFEA5' , u'\uFEA7' , u'\uFEA8' , u'\uFEA6' ) ,
 u'\u062F' : ( u'\uFEA9' , u'\uFEAA' ) ,
 u'\u0630' : ( u'\uFEAB'  , u'\uFEAC' ) ,
 u'\u0631' : ( u'\uFEAD' , u'\uFEAE' ) ,
 u'\u0632' : ( u'\uFEAF'  , u'\uFEB0' ) ,
 u'\u0633' : ( u'\uFEB1' , u'\uFEB3' , u'\uFEB4' , u'\uFEB2' ) ,
 u'\u0634' : ( u'\uFEB5' , u'\uFEB7' , u'\uFEB8' , u'\uFEB6' ) ,
 u'\u0635' : ( u'\uFEB9' , u'\uFEBB' , u'\uFEBC' , u'\uFEBA' ) ,
 u'\u0636' : ( u'\uFEBD' , u'\uFEBF' , u'\uFEC0' , u'\uFEBE' ) ,
 u'\u0637' : ( u'\uFEC1' , u'\uFEC3' , u'\uFEC4' , u'\uFEC2' ) ,
 u'\u0638' : ( u'\uFEC5' , u'\uFEC7' , u'\uFEC8' , u'\uFEC6' ) ,
 u'\u0639' : ( u'\uFEC9' , u'\uFECB' , u'\uFECC' , u'\uFECA' ) ,
 u'\u063A' : ( u'\uFECD' , u'\uFECF' , u'\uFED0', u'\uFECE' ) ,
 u'\u0640' : ( u'\u0640' ) ,
 u'\u0641' : ( u'\uFED1' , u'\uFED3' , u'\uFED4' , u'\uFED2' ) ,
 u'\u0642' : ( u'\uFED5' , u'\uFED7' , u'\uFED8' , u'\uFED6' ) ,
 u'\u0643' : ( u'\uFED9' , u'\uFEDB' , u'\uFEDC' , u'\uFEDA' ) ,
 u'\u0644' : ( u'\uFEDD' , u'\uFEDF' , u'\uFEE0', u'\uFEDE' ) ,
 u'\u0645' : ( u'\uFEE1' , u'\uFEE3' , u'\uFEE4' , u'\uFEE2' ) ,
 u'\u0646' : ( u'\uFEE5' , u'\uFEE7' , u'\uFEE8' , u'\uFEE6' ) ,
 u'\u0647' : ( u'\uFEE9' , u'\uFEEB' , u'\uFEEC' , u'\uFEEA' ) ,
 u'\u0648' : ( u'\uFEED' , u'\uFEEE' ) ,
 u'\u0649' : ( u'\uFEEF' , u'\uFEF0' ) ,
 u'\u064A' : ( u'\uFEF1' , u'\uFEF3' , u'\uFEF4' , u'\uFEF2' )
}
```

Comment: Is there any arabic reshaper in JAVA ?

Comment: How about arabic reshaper in c#?

Comment: @BigOther, Apologies for the direct approach. I noticed you were involved in a previous Arabic SE site proposal. So I thought you may be interested to support a new one. Please spread the word to get wider support: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123866/arabic-language?referrer=Yzc1MjllM2QwMjVkMGFhN2ZkNTljYzM4MGFhYjQ5ZDZlZmY4NWQ1ZDRhZTY1NWFjOGE1ZTZhNzVlNTc5OGIzNT_lCSOrW5jf30GiLzwp9ms6fpZke2NZMMUtT1-AZELs0

Comment: To convert shaped characters to unshaped characters, (or to use different terminology, general charaters to presentational characters), you can use `unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", string)` or `unicodedata.normalize.("NFKD", string)` as well.

Answer (score 5):

Arabic has 5 blocks of characters reserved for it in [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/):

- U+0600 .. U+06FF Arabic
- U+0750 .. U+077F Arabic Supplement
- U+08A0 .. U+08FF Arabic Extended A
- U+FB50 .. U+FDFF Arabic Presentation Forms A
- U+FE70 .. U+FEFF Arabic Presentation Forms B

The example text in the question is all encoded with the 4 code points:

- UTF-8 0xD8 0xB9 = U+0639 = ARABIC LETTER AIN
- UTF-8 0xD8 0xB1 = U+0631 = ARABIC LETTER REH
- UTF-8 0xD8 0xA8 = U+0628 = ARABIC LETTER BEH
- UTF-8 0xD9 0x89 = U+0649 = ARABIC LETTER ALEF MAKSURA

Additionally, there are spaces and some occurrences of:

- UTF-8 0xE2 0x80 0x8E = U+200E = LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK (LRM)

The fact that the Arabic letters are displayed differently despite the same Unicode code point being used to store the data shows that you will need to adapt the glyph that is displayed to its position relative to other characters (beginning, middle, end of word, or standalone).  You can read Chapter 9 ([Middle East–I](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode8.0.0/ch09.pdf)) to find out a lot more about the handling of Arabic text.